# 'Safe' temperatures for use

Tags: hardware, temperature

So I need to measure the temperature in my conservatory, and with all the doors shut on a summer's day it gets pretty toasty (uncomfortable for more than a few seconds).

My question is what sort of temperature range would be OK to use the Pi in?

Comment: The Pi is meant to be beat on. I highly doubt you will fire it. Do you have it overclocked?

Comment: Yeah, Modest (800mHz, 0 overvolt)

Comment: I agree with the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use the power of google://"raspberry pi temperature range" to find out that RPi is good between 0 and 70 degrees celsius (taken from [pi hardware general specifications](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/hardware-general-specifications))

Answer (score 0):

According to the raspberry blog it's 85 degrees Celcius: http://www.raspberrypi.org/introducing-turbo-mode-up-to-50-more-performance-for-free/